# Advanced PDF - Trouble adding small table to header to appear on each page

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to add a small table to the header of the advanced PDF for a picking ticket. These fields need to appear on each page to help delivery staff if the pages get separated. I have tried all of the ways I can think of to get this to work, but the table disappears when I test it. I am new to HTML, so it is hard to understand where the issue is. Below is what I am working with. I tried putting the table before the  but that either gives an error or makes the table disappear. The table in question is the end of the code block below with Route Date, Truck Number and Stop Number.

```
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <macrolist>
        <macro id="nlheader">
            <table class="header" style="width: 100%;"><tr>
    <td rowspan="3"><#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0><img src="http://XXXXXXX.shop.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=11&amp;c=7203566&amp;h=NSaadJ6sqFB7h5yvBSShikbm1V16LLZpMjxRBnK83Udek2SH" style="float: left; margin: 7px; width: 250px; height: 141px;" /> </#if></td>
    <td align="right"><span class="title">${record@title}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><span class="number">Sales Order#${record.tranid}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">${record.trandate}</td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
        <macro id="nlfooter">
            <table class="footer" style="width: 100%;"><tr>
    <td><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
    <td align="right"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
    <style type="text/css">* {
        <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
        <#else>
            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
        </#if>
        }
        table {
            font-size: 9pt;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8pt;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 5px 6px 3px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            color: #333333;
        }
        td {
            padding: 4px 6px;
        }
        td p { align:left }
        b {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #333333;
        }
        table.header td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table.footer td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 8pt;
        }
        table.itemtable th {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        table.body td {
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        td.addressheader {
            font-size: 8pt;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }
        td.address {
            padding-top: 0;
        }
        span.title {
            font-size: 28pt;
        }
        span.number {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        span.itemname {
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 150%;
        }
        hr {
            width: 100%;
            color: #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #d3d3d3;
            height: 1px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body header="nlheader" header-height="10%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="20pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td class="addressheader"><b>${record.shipaddress@label}</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="address">${record.shipaddress}</td>
    </tr></table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Route Date</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Truck Number</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Stop Number</p>
    </th>
    </tr>
</thead><tr>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody54}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody53}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody50}</p>
    </td>
    </tr></table>
```

I have tried moving the code block to inside the  block, but the from throws an error or does not display the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the table inside the header and adjust the height.
I added 2 comment in your code

```
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <macrolist>
        <macro id="nlheader">
            <table class="header" style="width: 100%;"><tr>
    <td rowspan="3"><#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0><img src="http://XXXXXXX.shop.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=11&amp;c=7203566&amp;h=NSaadJ6sqFB7h5yvBSShikbm1V16LLZpMjxRBnK83Udek2SH" style="float: left; margin: 7px; width: 250px; height: 141px;" /> </#if></td>
    <td align="right"><span class="title">${record@title}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><span class="number">Sales Order#${record.tranid}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">${record.trandate}</td>
    </tr></table>

<!-- Your table has been moved here, you can remove this comment -->

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Route Date</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Truck Number</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
    <p align="center">Stop Number</p>
    </th>
    </tr>
</thead><tr>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody54}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody53}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p align="center">${record.custbody50}</p>
    </td>
    </tr></table>



        </macro>
        <macro id="nlfooter">
            <table class="footer" style="width: 100%;"><tr>
    <td><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
    <td align="right"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
    </macrolist>
    <style type="text/css">* {
        <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKsc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKtc, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKjp, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansCJKkr, sans-serif;
        <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
            font-family: NotoSans, NotoSansThai, sans-serif;
        <#else>
            font-family: NotoSans, sans-serif;
        </#if>
        }
        table {
            font-size: 9pt;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8pt;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 5px 6px 3px;
            background-color: #e3e3e3;
            color: #333333;
        }
        td {
            padding: 4px 6px;
        }
        td p { align:left }
        b {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #333333;
        }
        table.header td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table.footer td {
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 8pt;
        }
        table.itemtable th {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        table.body td {
            padding-top: 2px;
        }
        td.addressheader {
            font-size: 8pt;
            padding-top: 6px;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
        }
        td.address {
            padding-top: 0;
        }
        span.title {
            font-size: 28pt;
        }
        span.number {
            font-size: 16pt;
        }
        span.itemname {
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 150%;
        }
        hr {
            width: 100%;
            color: #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #d3d3d3;
            height: 1px;
        }
</style>
</head>

<!-- Adjust the header height 10% => 20% ?? and remove this comment -->

<body header="nlheader" header-height="10%" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="20pt" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="Letter">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><tr>
    <td class="addressheader"><b>${record.shipaddress@label}</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="address">${record.shipaddress}</td>
    </tr></table>
```